# Keep a variable in input field after submitting form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to keep a users email in the input field after submitting the form and have had this working previously but after changing a lot of code to mysqli from mysql, the email doesnt stay in the input box after submission.

**PhP Code**

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('connection.php');

$email = isset ($_POST['email'])&& isset ($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
if ($email){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
}
?>
```

**Html Code**

```
<form class ="form"  method ="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

Email:<input type="email" name="email" maxlength="30" value="<?php $email ?>" placeholder ="Enter Your Email"/>

<input id="button"type="submit" value="Get Security Question" name ="submit"/>
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working any more?

Comment: you are missing an `echo` in your html, it should be `value="<?php echo $email ?>"`

Comment: you hero, I didn't even think to look at that part as I thought there was nothing there I could have got wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to, you where missing the `echo` function.

```
Email:<input type="email" name="email" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $email ?>"
```

And i would also like to recommend changing

```
$email = isset ($_POST['email'])&& isset ($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
```

To

```
$email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
```

Effect is the same but its way cleaner and the second `&& isset ($_POST['email'])` wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing `echo` in your code. Just change it like this.

```
<input type="email" name="email" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $email ?>" placeholder ="Enter Your Email"/>
```

or short form of echo

```
<input type="email" name="email" maxlength="30" value="<?= $email ?>" placeholder ="Enter Your Email"/>
```